# What do these numbers mean for the S&P?

Tags: stock-exchanges, market-indexes

1. What does the numbers for the S&P mean in the image below? For example, on 18th October, it says S&P -5.60. What does the -5.60 mean? I looked at the S&P Open, High, Low and Close prices for the S&P Index, but I don't know where the -5.60 comes from.
2. What does USB, and the numbers associated with it mean?

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXSP%3A.INX&ei=aAuBUJjKOMiekAXR_wE

[image]

(I got the chart from the site dailyspeculations.com)

Comment: The image showing -5.60 and USB, has no context. Where is it from?

Comment: Thanks. I got it from http://www.dailyspeculations.com/

Any idea what those numbers mean?

Comment: No. They are not the change in the S&P index. Perhaps they're a near-month Future contract value. The site itself talks about all kinds of non-finance stuff. Why not ask them there? There was no obvious explanation of these numbers I saw.

Comment: It looks like it is their predicted daily return on the index, after doing some basic subtraction between many of the listed dates they don't seem far off of the real daily returns of the index.

Comment: Tbanks guys :) Most appreciated, will further try to find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB is the ticker for US Bancorp. The numbers to me look like their prediction of the return for the day, I could be wrong but I think that's what it is.

Comment: So they predict S&P and USB each day? That's it?

Comment: Thanks, most appreciated! Seems a bit unusual though..

Comment: it does indeed seem most odd, well at lest just for USB but that's what it seems like they are doing to me, no real description makes it hard to tell but by calculating a few of the returns and look at what they had it seems like that's what they are doing.

Comment: Agreed, it IS strange! What do the color codes mean for different days? As @JoeTaxpayer said, the site covers many non-finance topics. Some is great reading! I searched the site for 'USB' or 'US Bancorp', found nothing. I checked source, no joy there. As of market close today, no values for SPX or USB were entered for 23 Oct, only through 22 Oct. I wonder if it will update in the morning tomorrow? Source shows SPX & USB values hard coded by day. Or: Maybe it's a notice board, with the strategy on a separate page/site? Nothing wrong with that. Please tell us if you learn more, okay? Thanks!!!

Comment: Just one question, especially towards @MCP_infiltrator , to calculate the return for the day, does one subtract the Open Price from the Close Price for each day?

Comment: The color codes...got me on that one, I have not a clue.

Comment: @Richard80 very sorry for such a tardy response but a daily return is calculated as follows:
(price today)/(price yesterday) - 1